# Change width in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, pandas-styles

I am using pandas and trying to set the same width for all the columns in the DataFrame, I have tried both `width` and `min_width` but they had no effect.

Code snippet:

```
s2 = df.style
s2.use(style.set_table_styles(
        [{
                'selector': 'th',
                'props': [
                    ('background-color', 'rgb(235, 245, 255)'),
                    ('text-align', 'center'),
                    ('width', '200px')]
            },
            {
                'selector': 'td',
                'props': [
                    ('text-align', 'center')]
            }
        ])
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this -

```
import pandas as pd

styles = [
    {
        'selector': 'th',
        'props': [
            ('background-color', 'rgb(235, 245, 255)'),
            ('text-align', 'center'),
            ('width', '200px')]
    },
    {
        'selector': 'td',
        'props': [
            ('text-align', 'center')]
    }
]

html = df.style.set_table_styles(styles)

html
```

Comment: Isn't this for the maximum width of the column? I would like to force the width to be a certain amount.

Comment: Sorry, try the updated code.